# ASP.NET 4.5 Connection string to SQL Server 2019 - "An error occurred while communicating with the database"

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, iis, sql-server-2019

So my company has an old legacy .NET 4.5 web application running on IIS (version 8.5.9600.16384) in which it's application database resides on Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3)... This works perfectly fine.

However (due to decommissioning / upgrades) we want to move the database to our SQL Server 2019 Server. So I took the original .NET package and re-imported it >> during the wizard I entered the SQL Server 2019 Server / db path and renamed the solution name with '_TEST' suffix >> then restarted IIS. The resulting connection string looks like this (as expected / mirroring the original working one however with the new server / db / uname):
[connection string in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndtZC.png)

When I go to test logging in to the web application (via IE11), I get the following "an error occurred while communicating with the database" error after clicking login:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xS4W.png)

We also tested the same exact SQL Server 2019 connection string through Powershell on this same web server and we are able to connect into the database, so it would seem that there's some mechanism failing inside the .NET application whether there's a configuration or driver not quite right somewhere.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I could potentially try next or what the issue might be here?

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point in your code? Or changing the code so it logs or displays the actual error instead of a useless "An error occurred" message? It would literally be trial and error with nothing more to go on than something went wrong. I see three connection strings from your config file and nothing in the error even suggests which of those databases the error occurred on.

Comment: Before wasting your time debugging .NET client code have you checked that the new SQL Server 2019 instance is actually setup correctly? In SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager is the TCP/IP protocol enabled for the instance? What port/s is it listening on? Does Windows Firewall allow local subnet connections (I assume) to those port/s? Can you successfully telnet to those port/s from the IIS server? Once all that's in place what happens if you change `Data Source=MYSERVER;` to `Server=MYSERVER,YourPortNumber;`?

Comment: Yeah I checked with our DBA and he said the ports shouldn't be needed by default but I appended the conn string with the port anyway but still got the same error message. I think the TCP/IP thing is not a problem as we have other web applications hosted on this same SQL server instance.

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah my colleague has tried debugged in the IDE, we have the same problem unfortunately, I'll try and ascertain more detail though and post a proper update

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to use the correct connectionstring. I know it works in your previous sql server 2014. Please follow the below steps to get the connection string, and replace it in your `web.config`. And the settings sync to your IIS.

**If there also have any errors, you can update your post.**

#### Steps

1. open your vs2019, and open `sql server object explorer` .

   [image]
2. Add new server, and type the information to connect your sql server 2019.

   [image]
3. After connect to the sql server, please click the `Properties` to copy the `Connection string`.

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: My colleague gave this a go as per your steps, we still get the same error message in the front end web page. Thanks for the suggestion.